# jQuery click on action link not doing anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have a button which when i click it i would like it to click a hidden action link.

The click on the action link is not doing anything. but if i click the action link my self it works, just not when i make jquery click it?

```
function myClickFunction() {
   $('#CloseLink').click();
   //$(document).on("CloseLink", "click", function())
}

<input id="btnClose" type="button" value=" Close " onclick="myClickFunction()"/>
  <div style="visibility:hidden">
     @Html.ActionLink("Close", "APClientIndex", "Home", null, new { id="CloseLink", @class = "btn btn-primary niceButton" })
  </div>
```

Plain html:

```
<input id="btnClose" type="button" value=" Close " onclick="myClickFunction()">
<div style="visibility:hidden">
  <a class="btn btn-primary niceButton" href="/Home/APClientIndex" id="CloseLink">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post the plain HTML instead of your template ?

Comment: Try: `$('#CloseLink')[0].click()`

Comment: Calling `$('#CloseLink').click();` will just trigger click event handlers you have already attached and won't trigger the default browser behaviour

Comment: @tewathia Thanks, that looks to have done the trick, could you explain what the [0] does? and then i can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Pomster The jQuery `click` method fires the `onclick` event of that element. In order to simulate a click on an anchor `a` tag, you need to run the `click` method of the DOM element itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#CloseLink')[0].click()
```

Is what i used as suggested by tewathia in the comments section.

The jQuery click method fires the onclick event of that element. In order to simulate a click on an anchor a tag, you need to run the click method of the DOM element itself.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to simulate the user clicking an anchor tag, I don't think that is possible with javascript

What you can do is read the anchor tag's href attribute and change the window location manually:

```
function myClickFunction() {
  var href = $('#CloseLink').attr("href");
  window.location.href = href;
}
```

Comment: $('#CloseLink')[0].click() is what i used as suggested by tewathia in the comments section above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do is to fire the click action by javascript?

With `$('#CloseLink').click();` you are not firing the click event, you are binding an action to the click, but you don't have any function inside like `$('#CloseLink').click(function(){...});`

So if you want to fire the click event you need to do `$('#CloseLink').trigger('click');`

Comment: `.click()` without arguments is actually a shortcut for `.trigger( "click" )` see [here](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: @ajimenez you can trigger a click with `.click()`, see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: This answer is wrong, first because .click() raises the click event, and because it will have no effect on an anchor tag

Comment: Yes you are right, is a shortcut, the problem is that you can trigger the action click but this action is not doing the redirection.

If you want to use the redirection you need to change location.href


    `$('#CloseLink').click(function(){
        window.location.href = $('#CloseLink').attr("href");
    });`